# Stokes Theorem on a sphere problem

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'm looking through my multivariable calculus notes and have come across a question I'm not sure I fully understand. It reads, "If $\omega$ is a differential form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $M$ is a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ what is
$$\int_M \,d\omega$$
The answer is 0, according to the answer in the back and I think it's zero because,
$$\int_M \,d\omega = \int_{\partial M}\omega$$
from Stokes theorem, but since the sphere does not have a boundary then
$$\int_{\partial M}\omega=0$$
Where my confusion is, if it does not have a boundary how can one be sure the integral even exists, why does it have to be zero?

Comment: Why would the integral not exist?

Comment: The boundary of the sphere is the empty set, so integrating over the empty set gives you $0$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You can split the sphere into half spheres, apply the theorem on each half, and see that the answers cancel.